# Limit Entity Reference Options depending on one of the referenced content type fields value

Tags: nodes

I have two content types Cylinder Master and Association. Cylinder Master contains all the cylinder details and an Allocation status field(Allocated/Unallocated). In Association I am referencing the Cylinder Master fields but I want to just display the Unallocated cylinders list. How can I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Drupal 8?

For each content type you can manage the reference type for each field. Setting "Reference method" to "Views: Filter by an entity reference view" you can use different settings for different content types.

First create a view with entity reference list of Cylinder Master content filtered by allocation status, then set the Association content types reference method to use the view.

Comment: Thanks, will try the solution. Is there any way to update the allocation status of Cylinder Master to Allocated after Association is done and content is saved?

Comment: You could probably update the referenced node using core Actions module or entity update hook. But depending on the site's overall functionality you probably could also use the reference field to check association status (whether the field has a value or not).